# I can't write data into csv by schedule

Tags: python, csv, file, schedule

I set schedule 30 seconds, but data will write in csv every 1-2 seconds...
I try a lot of ways to fix it, but there is no use.
Hope my get data write in csv every 30 seconds.
Hope somebody can help me solve it, thanks a lot!

```
import bs4
import requests
import schedule
import time
import smtplib
import email.message
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
from function import send_email
from datetime import datetime as dt
import csv


stock_no = input('Please insert stock no：')
set_price = '%.2f' % float(input('Please set notification price:'))


def get_stock_price():
    links = 'https://histock.tw/stock/%s' % stock_no
    response = requests.get(links)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    tittle = soup.find('h3').get_text().strip()
    li = soup.find('span', id="Price1_lbTPrice").span.get_text()
    time_now = dt.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    with open('C:/Python workspace/stock_value_notification/index.csv', 'a', newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow([tittle, li, time_now])

    return li, tittle, time_now


schedule.every(10).seconds.do(get_stock_price)

while True:
    try:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
        current_price = get_stock_price()[0]

        if set_price == current_price:
            msg_text = get_stock_price()[1] + \
                'stock value is  ' + current_price
            send_email(msg_text)
            toaster = ToastNotifier()
            toaster.show_toast("Stock value notification",
                               msg_text,
                               duration=10)
    except:
        print('It is not working...')
        break
```

[this csv file is the result I program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu0b3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the schedule the wrong way.
I hope this pesudo code example will help you:

```
def scrape_and_save():
    res = scrape()
    save_to_csv(res)

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(scrape_and_save)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Oh! I got it!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the notify section into either a separate function or into `get_stock_price()`. Here is a working refactored code.

Schedule will call `get_stock_price` every interval and notification is later called once data is written into the o/p file.

Adjust your it according to your need further.

```
import bs4
import requests
import schedule
import time
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
from datetime import datetime as dt
import csv
import sys

stock_no = input('Please insert stock no：')
set_price = '%.2f' % float(input('Please set notification price:'))


def get_stock_price():
    try:
        links = 'https://histock.tw/stock/%s' % stock_no
        response = requests.get(links)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        tittle = soup.find('h3').get_text().strip()
        li = soup.find('span', id="Price1_lbTPrice").span.get_text()
        time_now = dt.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    
        with open('index.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            writer.writerow([tittle, li, time_now])
    
        notify(li, tittle)

    except Exception as e:
        print('It is not working...')
        print(e)
        sys.exit()


def notify(current_price, stock_title):

    if set_price == current_price:
        msg_text = stock_title + \
                   ' stock value is  ' + current_price
        toaster = ToastNotifier()
        toaster.show_toast("Stock value notification",
                           msg_text,
                           duration=10)

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(get_stock_price)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

PS: webscraping activity may cause additional delay sometimes adding to the execution time.

Comment: I’m grateful to solved this question!! It's give me a lot help.